# Update variables values inside a dictionary

Tags: swift, variables, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'd like to update variables used from a dictionary like I can update `static var` declared variables and have their updated value available anywhere in the code.

Here is what I mean when using `dict`:

```
class Main1 {

    static var value1 : Int = 1

    func updateValue(_ value: String) {

        let dict : [String : Int] = ["value1": Main1.value1]

        let dict1 = dict[value]
        guard var value = dict1 else { return }

        value = value + 1
        print(value)
    }
}

class Main2 {

    func updateValue(_ value: String) {

        let dict : [String : Int] = ["value1": Main1.value1]

        let dict1 = dict[value]
        guard var value = dict1 else { return }

        value = value + 1
        print(value)
    }
}

Main1().updateValue("value1") //2
Main2().updateValue("value1") //2 <--- I need 3 here!
```

Here it works with `static var`:

```
class Main3 {

    static var value1 : Int = 1

    func updateValue() {
        Main3.value1 = Main3.value1 + 1
        print(Main3.value1)
    }
}

class Main4 {
    func updateValue() {
        Main3.value1 = Main3.value1 + 1
        print(Main3.value1)
    }
}

Main3().updateValue() //2
Main4().updateValue() //3
```

I read NSMutableDictionary could be an answer but I had no luck setting up something like that yet. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: fundamentally you are mixing a few things together quite badly here, but briefly the situation is: the `value` (after your `guard`) has no 2-way binding to the original value in the dictionary, but twisting one more on the situation: the actual value in the dictionary has no 2-way binding to the actually `static` variable – which means you are dealing with 3 different copies of the original _value_.

Comment: Which also means I'm totally screwed right? I actually think it was more wishful thinking than mixing things together because this would have been an incredibly easy solution to use... Do you have something to recommend?

Comment: I would __not__ recommend to start playing with (raw-)pointers in Swift, because the actual working solution would generate more concerns than could resolve – evaluate it like: your concept had been dead before it was actually born.

Comment: It actually makes sense! What would be a solution for me here? Keep on using five different functions doing the same thing just so I can update the original `static vars`? To keep a single function for every variables but having the new values saved into new static vars after they've been updated to be used in another class?

Comment: probably you are facing to typical XY problem here: basically the original concept about to create such global variables is a warning sign of the architecture of your project has been derailed really badly somewhere before, what problem you'd like to compensate by creating another (probably a much bigger) problem in your project – I'd recommend to step back and start thinking about 1. _why_ would you need the global variables at the first place? and 2. _how_ could you get rid of them entirely?

Comment: You might have guessed this is my first project, and I'm glad you showed up today to make me think differently than I was yesterday. 1. I'm using global variables to access the values in different files and classes, I don't know if this is good practice but it's been working great. 2. I have no clue about how to get rid of them entirely